# A lot of commands on Ubuntu 16.04 fail to execute:

Tags: 16.04, shared-library, qemu

A lot of commands on Ubuntu 16.04 fail to execute:

Recently, I was learning about QEMU, as well as being able to build Debian ARM64 root file system, so maybe I was wrong to execute some commands :(. Thank you.

Examples:

```
~$ sudo reboot  /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such
file or directory

~$ sudo service tftpd-hpa restart;
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory

hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$ sudo reboot 
[sudo] password for hoan: 
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory
hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$
```

@steeldriver: thank for your comments

```
hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$ uname -m
x86_64
hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$
```

How to fix this, thank you

Comment: What is the actual machine architecture (`uname -m`)? are any foreign architectures enabled (`dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`)?

Comment: Seems to be located in [`libc6:arm64` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ld-linux-aarch64.so.1&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any).

Comment: @steeldriver. Thankyou, how to fix this broblem  hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$ uname -m
x86_64
hoan@hoan-pfiev09:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

Comment: @N0rbert ,@steeldriver : Maybe because I made some wrong commands, make the library link is faulty, or misconfigured the architecture of the computer, I do not know anymore :(.

Comment: @steeldriver , I just added the information, do you have any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @NguyễnAnHoan - not really, no - it's not clear to me why your system would think that it needs an ARM dynamic linker. It *might* just be a matter of running `sudo ldconfig` to update the links / cache. Otherwise you may need to dig into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` to see if you can find what software is associated with the library.

Comment: @steeldriver Recently, I was learning about QEMU, as well as being able to build Debian ARM64 root file system, so maybe I was wrong to execute some commands :(.
Thank you.